# Parallel.For domain decomposition C#

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I would like to know:

How do the iterations spitted between processors , statically (each processor 
gets N/(#processors) iterations) , dynamically (Every processor gets one iteration and then comes back for another one) , can I choose the policy ?

Thank You!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Parallel.ForEach()` method uses a Partitioner, you can provide [a custom one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997411.aspx).

Couldn't find a direct link to say the same for `Paralle.For()` just yet.

Comment: Thank You! It was exactly what I needed ! Do you know if there is possibility to make Parallel.Foreach run in serial mode under specific condition? Kind of Partitioner that gives all the work to one processor.

Comment: Yes, though it kind of defeats the purpose of `Parallel.`. But i have noticed that the default partitioner for `.For()` will run small sets in 1 Thread.

Comment: @Sergey Kucher: What you are asking should be possible by calling `Parallel.ForEach` with `ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism` set to 1.

Comment: @Tudor: that certainly is another way to beat the system... But I think Sergey wants something that dynamically depends on the dataset.